# Can't see console.log in routes.js using node webkit and express

Tags: node.js, logging, desktop-application, node-webkit

I am developing a desktop app using node webkit and express. I use sublime build system to debug. I can see client pages log. But in routes I can't see any logs or alert message in sublime console, cmd console and nodewebkit devtool.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Hello');
    // my code
});
```

I am sure it's hit since my page is rendered. Sorry I am new to node-webkit. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your routes file isn't being hit. Try including the following in your app.js:

```
var router = express.Router();    
var routes = require('./app/routes.js'); //the path to your routes file
router.use('/',routes);
```

Also in your routes file you will need a few requires:

```
   var express = require('express'),
    app = express().Router();
```

As far as debugging, I use node-inspector, you can install it via npm install node-inspector. They have instructions on their [page](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) of how to use it, but it's basically similar to a Chrome inspector console, you should set a breakpoint on your route function, to see if it's being triggered.

This is documented on the [Express page](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) under the express.Router() section at the bottom of the page, you will need to include the Router function in your call to break out your routes into a different file

If that doesn't work, you can post more of your code and we can try to help out.

Comment: Hi, I think I have hit routes file. I have require('./server/routes')(app) in app.js. and the render function is executed in routes.js

Comment: ok, you just need to tell express to use that route file when a certain route is requested with "app.use('/',routes);" Where "routes" is the name of the variable you set to require your routes file

Comment: Thanks. It turns out I didn't include var router = express.Router(); It works